# Issues with RPN Calculator add method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build an add method for an RPN Calculator:

```
function RPNCalculator() {
  if (!(this instanceof RPNCalculator)) return new RPNCalculator();
}

RPNCalculator.prototype.arr = [];

RPNCalculator.prototype.sum=0;


RPNCalculator.prototype.push = function(num){
  this.arr.push(num);
  return this.arr;  
};

RPNCalculator.prototype.plus = function(){
   var newarr = [];
   for (var i = this.arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        newarr.push(this.arr[i]);
   }

   this.sum = newarr.reduce(function(p, n){
      return p + n;
   }, 0);

   return this.sum;
};
```

The problem is—in the tests I am comparing my method to, it appears they want to add two values at a time.

This is from the test:

```
  it('adds three numbers', function() {
    // Infix: 2+3+4
    // Postfix: 2 3 4 + +
    rpnCalculatorInstance.push(2);
    rpnCalculatorInstance.push(3);
    rpnCalculatorInstance.push(4);
    rpnCalculatorInstance.plus();
    expect(rpnCalculatorInstance.value()).toEqual(7);
    rpnCalculatorInstance.plus();
    expect(rpnCalculatorInstance.value()).toEqual(9);
  });
```

With my version you run it once and it would add all the values in the array—in the test version it seems to be adding the first two values upon calling the method and the next time around (when the method is called) the sum of the first call is being added to the next value.

Initially that sounded a lot like the reduce method, but apparently that's not the case. So can someone explain how to implement the way the test outline and why would that be logical? What utility is there to have the values stored but only increment two at a time?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

```
RPNCalculator.prototype.sum = 0;


RPNCalculator.prototype.push = function(num){
  this.arr.push(num);
  return this.arr;  
};

RPNCalculator.prototype.plus = function(){
   this.sum += this.arr.push(this.arr.pop() + this.arr.pop());
};

RPNCalculator.prototype.pop = function() {
    return this.arr.pop();
};


 RPNCalculator.prototype.value = function(){
   return this.sum;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand RPN right, you need to pop the last two values of the stack and push the value after arithmetic operation, so you need some pop as well, like

```
RPNCalculator.prototype.pop = function() {
    return this.arr.pop();
};
```

With plus operator

```
RPNCalculator.prototype.plus = function() {
    this.arr.push(this.arr.pop() + this.arr.pop());
};
```

Comment: Thank you Nina! Would that mean then the value method (I didn't include it but its in the test) would always just get the last value in the array?

Comment: right, so works the hp-15c for example. the last result is the value of the stack.

Comment: Thanks Nina—I am still a little confused as I wasn't able to get the `subtracts two numbers, adds and subtracts, multiplies and divides` methods to work. I might have had too much wine at this point!